# Apache or PHP rewriting my URL to IP Address

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP/HTML5 app that requires an application.ini file parse the URL to determine a usage path. The DNS is configured correct, but when I attempt to hit the page I see that the domain name is being dropped and instead application.ini "sees" the ip address instead. I get the error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Resource_Exception' with message 'no domain settings for 555.16.8.69' in /var/www/html/library/<app>/Application/Resource/Domainsettings.php:63\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(683): Application_Resource_Domainsettings->init()\n#1 /var/www/html/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap
```

Where did the domain name go? I don't think my rewrite rules are doing anything strange:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

The real problem comes in a DomainSettings.php file with this line:
$this->getHost();

If you can't tell, I didn't write this code. I am attempting a port.

Comment: We need to see your routing config and possibly your vhost configuration.

Comment: I removed any virtualhosts, because they did not appear to do anything.

Comment: Basic httpd.conf setup:  



DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/httpdocs"
`<Directory "/var/www/html/httpdocs">
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>`

Comment: Did you configure `ServerName`?

Comment: Yes... Servername <mydomainname>.com

Comment: Wait... whay is your `DocumentRoot` not pointed to `/var/www/html/httpdocs/public`? (note i dont think this is necessarily the issue)